# Is there a way to query an array of JSON objects returned by a CTE in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have a PostgreSQL query that uses a CTE and the SELECT within the CTE uses json_agg() to aggregate data as JSON objects.  Is there a way to query the results of the CTE by searching for a specific object in the array based on the value of a field of objects?

For example, lets say the CTE creates a temporary table named results.  The values from the json_agg() is available in a field called owners, and each owner object has a field called name.  I want to SELECT * FROM results WHERE owner.name = 'John Smith'.  I am not sure how to write the WHERE clause below so that the name field of each object in the array of owners is checked for the value.

```
WITH results AS (
  -- some other fields here
  (SELECT json_agg(owners)
    FROM (
      SELECT id, name, telephone, email
      FROM owner
    ) owners   
  ) as owners
)
SELECT * 
FROM results 
WHERE owners->>'name' == 'John Smith'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that query you can typically use the `jsonpath` language after having converted your `json` data into `jsonb` data (see the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#DATATYPE-JSONPATH) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH)) :

```
WITH results AS (
  -- some other fields here
  (SELECT json_agg(owners)
    FROM (
      SELECT id, name, telephone, email
      FROM owner
    ) owners   
  ) as owners
)
SELECT * 
FROM results 
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(owners :: jsonb, '$[*] ? (@.name == "John Smith")')
```

Comment: sure you can use a regular expression inside the jsonpath with the filter operator `like_regex` see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-FILTER-EX-TABLE)